# How to resolve the conflict issue of using actionpack in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, actionpack

I have come here as my last resort to seek answer of my problem. My rails app is dependent on ruby-2.0.0 and rails 4.1.4(although I can go back to previous releases but not the one have to in order to resolve the issue) and I am trying to use `gem 'dotiw', '~> 1.1.1'` which is dependent on `[actionpack][1] (~> 3)`. Below message from console will give better understanding problem. Message report in terminal after running $`bundle install`

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    dotiw (~> 1.1.1) ruby depends on
      actionpack (~> 3) ruby

    rails (~> 4.1.4) ruby depends on
      actionmailer (= 4.1.4) ruby depends on
        actionpack (4.1.4)
```

As you can already see that I removed my `Gemfile.lock` and installed the bundle again. 
As a solution to my problem what I can do is either change my `rails` version or `gem 'dotiw', '~> 1.1.1'` changing the former will ramify my problem and reducing the version of latter will deprecate the some of functionality.  Also I don't understand why the this `gem 'dotiw', '~> 1.1.1'`  was not updated to support the latest releases of actionpack or better keep updating to support all future releases of it's dependencies.

Comment: There is nothing you can do other than either finding a replacement or fork of them gem that is compatible with 4.1 or creating one yourself (it could be as simple as changing the dependency in the gem's gemspec)

Comment: @Frederick, Thanks man it did work....! but, I had to toil for finding the right gemspec file for the gem.... And I hope it doesn't give birth to any other conflict in future. Technically it shouldn't but I am a newbie so I have my fears. By the way right location to change the file is "**~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dotiw-1.1.1/dotiw-1.1.1.gemspec**" for my version of rbenv and gems. Once again thanks man!!!

Comment: Just to point out that what you did may have worked but if you later deploy the app to a production environment (e.g. heroku) the problem will resurface.  @FrederickCheung suggestion is that you create a different version (fork the existing version) on GitHub to your own repo... then in the Gemfile you could do something like... `gem 'dotiw', :git => 'https://github.com/zeal_personal_repo/dotiw.git'` so that the "corrected" version is always loaded.